# Как передавать данные в поток ввода и принимать данные из потока вывода дочернего процесса?

Tags: linux, c, unix

Программа для Linux, на языке программирования C. В разрабатываемой мной программе с помощью функции fork создаётся дочерний процесс, который с помощью функции execl заменяется другой программой, которую я не могу менять. Как можно из моей программы передавать данные в поток ввода и получать данные из потока вывода дочернего процесса?

Есть тестовая программа, основанная на ответе @Yaroslav, почему-то не работает, дочерний процесс зависает на чтении, хотя из консоли работает, что я упустил?

Запускается parent child test

```
// parent.c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  if (argc < 3) {
    return 0;
  }
  
  char* in_str = argv[2];
  char out_str[10] = {};
  char* command = argv[1];
  int pin[2], pout[2], perr[2];
 
  pipe(pin);
  pipe(pout);
  pipe(perr);

  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
     /*Child*/
     close(pin[1]);
     dup2(pin[0], 0);
     close(pin[0]);

     close(pout[0]);
     dup2(pout[1], 1);
     close(pout[1]);

     close(perr[0]);
     dup2(perr[1], 2);
     close(perr[1]);
     execl(command, command, NULL);
     perror(command);
     exit(1);
  }
  /*Parent*/
  close(pin[0]);
  close(pout[1]);
  close(perr[1]);

  FILE *fin = fdopen(pin[1], "a");
  FILE *fout = fdopen(pout[0], "r");

  fprintf(fin, "%s\n", in_str);
  fflush(fin);
  fscanf(fout, "%s", out_str);
  printf("%s\n", out_str);

  wait(NULL);
  return 0;
}

// child.c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  char str[10];
  scanf("%s", str);
  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}

// child2.c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  int c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    putchar(c);
  }
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}

// build.sh
#!/bin/sh

gcc parent.c -o parent
gcc child.c -o child
gcc child2.c -o child2
```

Comment: Unix IPC 101. Почитайте `man dup` и около того.

Comment: Возможно вместо fork вам больше подойдет [forkpty](https://linux.die.net/man/3/forkpty) / В результате для связи между процессами у вас будет двунаправленный канал (со свойствами терминала)

Comment: @Максим Программа не зависает. Потоки работают в блокирующем режиме.  Это значит пока на канале не появились данные функция `read()` будет ждать . здесь или гарантировано нужно синхронизировать потоки или работать в не блокирующем режиме.

Comment: @Yaroslav, добавил вызов функции fflush(), вроде заработало. А как синхронизировать потоки? Внешними средствами или нужно их правильно настроить? И как можно работать в неблокирующем режиме? Всё равно ведь нужно ждать символа, только уже в основной программе. Мне надо получить что-то вроде bash, только управляемый программно, чтоб можно было сделать интерфейс к программе, которая интерактивно работает из виртуального терминала.

Comment: @Максим Если работаете с каналами в блокирующем режиме .синхронизировать потоки. это логически в программах не должно быть ситуации что оба потока зашли в функцию `read` и ожидают информации. И в таком режиме лучше использовать `read/write` функции. эти функции сразу выходят при появлении данных. функции `printf/scanf` могут ожидать заполнения буфера.

Comment: @Максим Если хотите работать в не блокирующем режиме, то открываете каналы используя `fcntl()` настраиваете работу в неблокирующем режиме , потом используя `poll()` ожидаете события на канале и когда появляются данные читаете их.

Answer (score 3):

Упрошено можно реализовать вот так, тем самым перенаправив стандартные потоки вводы/вывода на каналы. Дочерний процесс будет успешно читать/записывать в стандартные потоки. А родительский процесс будет читать/записывать из каналов.

```
char array[];
size_t len;
char command[];
char * argv[];
char * env[];
int pin[2], pout[2], perr[2];
 
pipe(pin);
pipe(pout);
pipe(perr);

pif_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
   /*Child*/
   close(pin[1]);
   dup2(pin[0], 0);
   close(pin[0]);

   close(pout[0]);
   dup2(pout[1], 1);
   close(pout[1]);

   close(perr[0]);
   dup2(perr[1], 2);
   close(perr[1]);
   execve(command, argv, env);
   perror(command);
   exit(1);
}
/*Parent*/
close(pin[0]);
close(pout[1]);
close(perr[1]);


read(pout[0], array, len);
read(err[0], array, len);
write(pin[1], array, len);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Как можно из моей программы передавать данные в поток ввода и получать
> данные из потока вывода дочернего процесса?

Гораздо проще эту задачу можно решить с помощью функции *popen()*:

```
man 3 popen

The  popen()  function opens a process by creating a pipe, forking, and invoking the shell.
```

Вам не нужно делать *fork()* и прочее, все эти заботы будут от Вас скрыты.

Однако, если в задани Вам написано, что надо **обязательно** использовать *fork()*, то идея там такая:

Когда выполняется *fork()*, то в память  созданного процесса копируется вся (!) память родительского. В том числе и дескрипторы файлов.

Перед вызовом *fork()* в родительском создаём канал с помощью вызова *pipe()* и закрываем в нём канал вывода.  После *fork()* в дочернем мы имеем тот же самый канал. Но в нём закрываем канал ввода.

Дочерний процесс начинает писать в свой конец канала, а родитель считывает из своего конца.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что при использовании popen возможно либо только чтение, либо только запись в дочерний поток?

Comment: @Максим Да. Создаётся пайп, у которого 2 конца (родитель и порождённый) и одно направление в пайпе.